# Is the statement that enumerators may appear whenever int is permitted redundant?

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer

I'm reading Standard `N2310` about enumerators and faced some misunderstanding.

6.7.2.2/3:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that
>   have type `int` and may appear wherever such are permitted.

Also

6.7.2.2/4:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type.

But the definition of **signed integer type** and **unsigned integer type** allows integer types wider then `int`. Actually:

6.2.5/4:

> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as 
>   `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. (These and other
>   types may be designated in several additional ways, as described in
>   6.7.2.) There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. 38) The standard and extended signed integer types are
>   collectively called signed integer types. 39)

---

So it is legitimate for a compiler to choose `long long int` or `char` as a representation for an enumerated type even though enumerators always have type `int`. Also *integer promotion* always converts to `int`. So if implementation chooses `long long int` or `char` for a enumeration type representation we will have assignment of incompatible types. Something like this:

```
//char is wide enough to hold all the values, let's choose it
enum something{
   a = 0,
   b  
};

enum something sth = a; //a has type int, but enum something is incompatible with int
                        //UB?
```

Should we do an explicit cast to stay strictly conforming?

```
enum something sth = (enum something) a;
```

Comment: `assignment of incompatible types`  anyway `a` will get implicitly converted to the compatible integer type of the `something` enum. It's like `char sth2 = a;`. A character constant has the type `int`, but you never do `char c = (char)'x';`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Actually, did not notice this. `6.5.16/2` states this explicitly: _In simple assignment ( = ), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand._ So even the types of enumeration and enumerators may be incompatible it gets converted to the right type nnyway.